# How to stop infinite email response loop coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion

I was testing the cfmail tag within coldfusion and kept refreshing the page and now my email is being spammed consistently with the same code that I wrote in the file. I tried to delete the file but my email keeps getting spammed with the code.

this isnt my real email but this is what I did pretty much. I tried deleting the file to stop the infinite email loop but I keep getting spammed in my email.

```
<cfmail to="myemail"
from="myemail"
subject="myemail"
type="text">
Dear myemail

We, here at Bedrock, would like to thank you for joining.

Best wishes
Barney
</cfmail>
<cfoutput>
    <p>Thank you test for registering.
     We have just sent you an email.</p>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: check the mailsent log to ensure that it's coming from the machine on which you wrote the code.

Comment: I managed to stop the loop I got over 30,000 emails in outlook. I solved it by restarting my IIS server.